# How to add background color to image property in css and html

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to change the background color of my image. Normally, to do this, I use;

```
.img {
background-image: url("./image.jpg");
background-color: "#3333";
}
```

But I am trying to do the same thing using the html img tag. But this doesn't seem to work. So in a form;

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="./image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In css...

```
.name -> Style is assigned to a "class="
#name -> Style is assigned to an "id="
 name -> Style is assigned to an tag <name></name>
```

You can try this: (Change .img to img in your CSS)

```
img {
 background-image: url("./image.jpg");
 background-color: #333;
}

<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="./image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**Note:** You will probably need a .png or other transparent image to see the background through the image.